# How can a machine with fixed output for all inputs be considered a Turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines

From [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/136043/115941), and the comments that follow:

> To clarify, this machine T′ with the fixed output for all inputs is a Turing machine? – Shashank V M

> @ShashankVM, Yes, T′ is a Turing machine. – D.W.♦ ([When can a deterministic finite-state-automata (DFSA) along with its input sequence be said to be a part of another DFSA?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/136014/when-can-a-deterministic-finite-state-automata-dfsa-along-with-its-input-seque/136043?noredirect=1#comment286521_136043))

From what I understand, a machine with fixed output for all inputs is a Turing machine.

**Consider this thought experiment**, I have a "machine" which is a wall with a slit through which I can pass a tape in. The "output" of this machine is on the wall, i.e. it is painted on the wall as a fixed string $S$, which for the purpose of this experiment is "Hello". So no matter what is written on the tape, the output of this "machine" is "Hello". From what I understand this "machine" is a Turing machine.

Is my understanding correct or am I missing something?

Because I find it hard to believe that this wall with a slit can be considered a Turing machine, when a supercomputer is considered a Deterministic Finite State Automaton.

Also I cannot see how this "machine" can emulate any another Turing machine or do any **useful computation**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different Turing machines. Each one runs a fixed, hardwired program. Most Turing machines do nothing useful; many of them just halt immediately.

Some are universal, meaning that they can emulate any other Turing machine given a description of its hardwired program as part of their input, but most aren't. The machine that always prints "Hello" obviously isn't universal, but it is a Turing machine.

Comment: Oh, I had forgotten that a universal turing machine is different from a turing machine.

Answer (score 3):

There's no notion of "can be considered to be a Turing machine".  Something either is a Turing machine, or it isn't.  There's a formal mathematical definition of what a Turing machine is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition

I never claimed that just because some process always produces the same output, that process must be a Turing machine.

There might be some confusion about Turing machines vs DFAs.  A computer could be modelled as a DFA (if we treat its memory size as fixed), or it could be modelled as a Turing machine (if we imagine that it's possible to gain more memory; or we just don't care to make use of the fact that memory size is fixed).  These two different ways to think about a computer have different advantages and disadvantages.  I suggest reading [Is a PDA as powerful as a CPU?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1868/755) and [How many gates until Turing Complete](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/72451/755) and [How does an automaton model a computer or something else?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/27645/755) and [How does an automaton actually "compute"?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/7042/755), as I suspect they get at the core issue you are struggling with.

Comment: Can you suggest a good textbook to study these topics?

Comment: @ShashankVM, Sipser is one standard textbook: http://math.mit.edu/~sipser/book.html

Comment: Thanks for this.